# Extract ticket number from string

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract the ticket numbers from a string that contains numbers and letters like:

```
String 1) Order 2555225552 Ticket Number [TICKET 201805000000012345]
String 2) Order 32234234234 Ticket Number [TICKET <span>201805000000012345</span>]
String 3) Order 5656567655665565 Ticket Number [  TICKET <span>   201805000000012345</span>   ]
```

I want here to get the number 201805000000012345 or any other number from input string (1, 2 or 3).

---

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/\[TICKET(.*)([0-9]+)(.*)\]/', 'Ticket Number [TICKET <span>201805000000012345</span>]', $matches);
```

Output:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "[TICKET <span>201805000000012345</span>]"
  1 => " <span>20180500000001234"
  2 => "5"
  3 => "</span>"
]
```

Comment: Can you add to your question what you have tried?  And I think the title `Extract ticket number from string` and `or any other number from input string` seems 2 different thing looking at the example data.

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) These 3 functions can solve your problems but you have to study them yourselves first.

Comment: use regex to find second number in your string

Comment: The problem is that the `(.*)` is greedy in nature. You need to make it non-greedy. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is mostly correct. You just need to add a `?` to make it non-greedy.

```
/\[TICKET(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)\]/
```

In fact, if you don't care about what comes after the numbers, you can also omit that part:

```
/\[TICKET(.*?)([0-9]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match()` solution:

```
$s = 'Order 5656567655665565 Ticket Number [  TICKET <span>   201805000000012345</span>';
preg_match('/TICKET [^0-9]*\K[0-9]+/', $s, $m);
$t_number = isset($m[0])? $m[0] : null;

print_r($t_number);
```

- `\K` - resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

---

The output:

```
201805000000012345
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex as simple as this will solve your problem:

```
'\D+\d+\D+(\d+)'
```

If you need you can also capture order:

```
'\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)'
```

This regex doesn't check if format is matched as in other answers, but if you know it will always be like in your examples then that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match('/\[TICKET(.*)([0-9]+)(.*)\]/', strip_tags('Ticket Number [TICKET <span>201805000000012345</span>]'), $matches);
print_r( $matches);
?>
```